# Question about variance and expected value of $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a random variable $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Assume I define $Y=|X|$ , How can I find Y's variance and expected value?

First I calculated its density directly and if I'm not mistaken it's $f_Y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(e^{\frac{-(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}{2}}-e^{\frac{-(\frac{x+\mu}{\sigma})^2}{2}})$.

Now $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mu\sigma$ but $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 f_Y(x)dx$ but I'm stuck with integrating this. The derivative of $e^{\frac{-(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}{2}}$ is $2\frac{(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2}e^{\frac{-(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2}{2}}$. Can I calculate the variance of Y in another way?

Comment: Did you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution ?

Comment: but I wonder how wikipedia got these functions?

Comment: Hint: $E[Y^2] = E[|X|^2] = E[X^2] = \mu^2 + \sigma^2$ and so you can find $\operatorname{var}(Y) = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2$ by evaluating $E[Y]$. Incidentally, $E[X] \neq \mu\sigma$ as you claim.

Comment: To elaborate on @Dilip's comment, if you're stuck with $\mathbb{E}(Y)$, start from $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(|\mu + z\sigma|)$ and write out the absolute value.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'll try. about $E[X]$ I meant $E[Y]$ (even I know $E[X]=\mu$). is it now correct?

Comment: No, $E[Y] \neq \mu\sigma$. You should get $E(Y) = \mu [1 - 2 \Phi(-\mu / \sigma)] + \sigma \sqrt{2 / \pi} \exp(-\mu^2 / 2 \sigma^2)$

Comment: Just by integrating directly $x\cdot f_Y(x)$? MuPAD says its $\mu\sigma$...

Comment: Here are the proper derivations: http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/FoldedNormal.html

About your direct integration: did you make sure to integrate over $[0,\infty)$?